# How to tag repository in Azure pipeline? You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action

Tags: git, azure, pipeline

There is a big project, it will clone multiple projects and build them. So I hope to tag these projects with a version tag.

But it prompts me to need 'GenericContribute' permission, logs below

```sh
git  -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" tag 1.15.11
git  -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" push origin 1.15.11
remote: 0000000000aaTF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\0dea3e47-c818-4a83-ae9d-0422c80128c5', scope 'repository'.
2020-07-16T11:11:55.7839182Z [11:11:55.780 INF] remote: TF401027: You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\0dea3e47-c818-4a83-ae9d-0422c80128c5', scope 'repository'.
```

[image: mypermission]

Answer (score 2):

I belevie that if you give permissons to your build service user it'll work.

[image]

Comment: The build service already have a `Create tag` permission by default. Why should I still need to assign a `Contribute` permission on it?