# You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action when pushing tags from Pipelines to Repo

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I think my issue is related to this post: [How to tag repository in Azure pipeline? You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62933675/910074)

By default, the build service User (`{Project Name} Build Service ({organization})`)  already have a `Create tag` permission.

I don't know why should I still need to assign a `Contribute` permission on it if I simply want to create a new tag?

Also, there is a `Tag sources` feature in the Azure Pipelines. The feature able to create a new tag without having the `Contribute` permission. I don't understand why. What's the different between `Tag sources` and `git push origin --tags`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check whether the identity "**`Project Collection Build Service ({organization})`**" has the permissions ("**`Contribute`**" and "**`Create tag`**") on the repository.

---

Go to "**Organization Settings**" (and "**Project Settings**") > "**Settings**" to check the following options:

- **`Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`**
- **`Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines`**

[image]

If the options are disabled, the pipeline will use the identity "**`Project Collection Build Service ({organization})`**". By default, this identity can allow the pipeline to access resources across projects within the current organization.

If the options are enabled, the pipeline will use the identity "**`{Project Name} Build Service ({organization})`**". By default, this identity can allow the pipeline to access resources only within current project.

For more details, you can reference the documentation "[**Job access tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

---

**EDIT:**

The "**`Tag sources`**" action is taken by another built-in service account "**`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS`**". It is a background service account that can only be called by the system of Azure DevOps. Users cannot use it and also cannot control its permissions.

When running some user-defined command lines or scripts in the pipeline to access resources in Azure DevOps, what users can use as authorization are below:

- The "**`System.AccessToken`**" for the project-scoped identity "**`{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})`**".
- The "**`System.AccessToken`**" for the collection-scoped identity "**`Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})`**".
- The PAT (Personal Access Token) for a user.

---

Comment: The `Tag sources` is able to create tag in the Azure Repo's repository without having a `Contribute` permission. Why?

Comment: I know I have to check the `Contribute` permission. I just don't know why. It because the `Tag sources` doesn't need that permission been set.

Comment: @WillHuang, Pushing tags to repository is making changes (or contributing to) at the repository level. Almost all the changes made at repository level need the '**`GenericContribute`**' (**`Contribute`**) permission be turned on at first. Then for certain particular actions, it also needs the corresponding separate permissions be turned on together.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your point. But my point is the `Tag sources` able to push tags to the Azure Repos, which method they used to push tags? Is there any way to push tags by not using `git push`?

Comment: @WillHuang, I have updated mu above answer with more information for your question (see **EDIT**). Check it.

Comment: @WillHuang, Is the information shared in my above answer helpful for you to understand? Do you have further questions about this?